# vuejs keyup working after tow key not one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

hi this is my html code

```
<journal_entries>
     <div slot='journal_entries' slot-scope="{lines,remove_the_opposite}">
        <tr class="o_data_row o_selected_row" v-for='(line , id) in lines' :key="line.uniq_prop">
            <td class="o_data_cell o_field_cell o_list_number">
                <div class="o_field_monetary o_field_number o_input o_field_widget">
                    <input v-model='line.debit' @keyup='remove_the_opposite(id,"debit")'>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</journal_entries>
```

and this is my vuejs2 code

```
remove_the_opposite:function(index,type)
{
    if(type == 'debit')
    {
        this.lines[index]['credit'] = 666;
    }
}
```

like this everything working so good but i have to do tow key up on `@keyup='remove_the_opposite(id,"debit")'` to change the value of the `lines[index]['credit']` its not change from the first keyup i have to do tow of them to change the value to 666 or whatever i want thanks a lot

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: I think this is caused by VueJS "Change Detection Caveats" if you are adding a new property to `this.lines[index]` object. more info: 

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats